# Best way to make milliondollarhomepage dynamic image grid?

Tags: .net, database, database-design, umbraco

I've been thinking about setting up a image grid similar to [milliondollarhomepage](http://www.milliondollarhomepage.com/) for a small domestic hobby idea , it would be dynamic. The grid would be around 500x500, I am wondering the best way to code this up, It can't be slow.

I am thinking it will work like this:

1. Users choose their place on the grid and upload their image.
2. The image is stored in the DB in a image type column
3. On rendering the page to the public, `.NET` cycles through all the uploaded images from the DB and dynamically creates the image based on each DB rows data & stored place in the square

The thing is I am not sure if this is a silly way to do it?

What do you guys think?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better off just recreating the image whenever somebody uploads a change. Assuming there will be far more visitors than contributors it would be wasteful to recreate the image for every request.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach sounds pretty reasonable to me.

Like Gordy said; you probably don't want to regenerate the image on each visit - but your code to generate the image and save it to the file system would be largely the same anyway.  Then, you can use a large HTML Map to define the individual ad's 'area'.  That will let you have different mouse-over text and URL when clicked.

Again, I'd be tempted to just generate the HTML file whenever you have a new client come on.  I mean, update your database and use .NET code to generate the HTML.  But the static html page with a static image is going to be a lot more performant than building anything dynamically.

Comment: I guess now it just comes down to how to freaken recreate a square image from all the rows of data. Given that their internal grids are all over the show, I wonder if JPGS draw left to right, or up to down ETC lol, definitely still got some research to do!